# How to add multiple parameters to a concurrent.futures map function?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am learning to use concurrent.futures in python and the function I want to test takes two parameters. I tried using "partial" to include the second parameter, but it didn't work. How can I make it work?

The below code DOES WORK for me:

```
def check_proxy(proxy,index):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    try:
        driver.get("https://ip.oxylabs.io/")
        return (f'{index}- {driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "pre").text}')
    except:
       return (f"{index} - Bad Proxy: {proxy} was removed from list")
   finally:
       driver.quit()

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
       list = []
        for x in range (len(proxies)):
            futures = executor.submit(check_proxy,proxies[x],x)
            list.append(futures)
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(list):
            print (future.result()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

The result of this code is what I would expect. a list of proxies showing that it all works.

```
2- 104.233.XX.YY
1- 140.99.XXX.XX
0- 104.227.XX.YY
3- 45.72.XX.YYY
4- 104.227.XX.YYY
```

When I try to use the executor.map and add the partial function to include the second parameter my results are all wrong.

```
def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        results = executor.map(partial(check_proxy,proxies),range(1,len(proxies)))
    for result in results:
        print (result)
```

Now the results are get are these:

```
1 - Bad Proxy: ['104.227.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '140.99.XXX.YY:ZZZZ', '104.233.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '45.72.XX.YYY:ZZZZ', '104.227.XX.YYY:ZZZZ'] was removed from list for Access Denied
2 - Bad Proxy: ['104.227.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '140.99.XXX.YY:ZZZZ', '104.233.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '45.72.XX.YYY:ZZZZ', '104.227.XX.YYY:ZZZZ'] was removed from list for Access Denied
3 - Bad Proxy: ['104.227.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '140.99.XXX.YY:ZZZZ', '104.233.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '45.72.XX.YYY:ZZZZ', '104.227.XX.YYY:ZZZZ'] was removed from list for Access Denied
4 - Bad Proxy: ['104.227.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '140.99.XXX.YY:ZZZZ', '104.233.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '45.72.XX.YYY:ZZZZ', '104.227.XX.YYY:ZZZZ'] was removed from list for Access Denied
5 - Bad Proxy: ['104.227.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '140.99.XXX.YY:ZZZZ', '104.233.XX.YY:ZZZZ', '45.72.XX.YYY:ZZZZ', '104.227.XX.YYY:ZZZZ'] was removed from list for Access Denied
```

Why is this and how can I fix it? Is there a way to use `executor.map(partial)` to include more parameters to my function and still make it work? Or any other way to use `executor.map` and pass more than one parameter to the function

Can you please also help me understand why I am seeing this result? I don't understand how the partial is making the function test all proxies at the same time.

Comment: Your code are full of errors, which I cannot run, thus it is hard for me to help. Please help us to help you by posting code that does not contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use partial here, instead just:

```
indicies = range(1, len(proxies) + 1)
results = executor.map(check_proxy, proxies, indicies)
```